# How to use Local with reflection in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, reflection

Maybe this is a very simple thing, but I couldn't find the answer. Can I write the following piece of code using reflection?

```
AdminEntities context= new AdminEntities(); 
datagridview1.DataSource = context.TABLENAME.Local.ToBindingList();
```

I have tried the following:

```
BindingSource rtBindingSource = new BindingSource();
var TableName = cboSelectTable.Text.ToString();
AdminEntities context = new AdminEntities();
var rawData = context.GetType().GetProperty(TableName).GetValue(context, null);
var truncatedData = ((IQueryable<object>)rawData).Local.ToBindingList();
var binding = new BindingList<object>(truncatedData);
rtBindingSource.DataSource = new BindingSource { DataSource = binding };
datagridview1.DataSource = rtBindingSource;
```

but it gives error:'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'Local' and no extension method 'Local' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' could be found

Comment: you can certainly do this by using reflection but the important question is _why_ do you need this? what is your actual goal?

Comment: I have multiple tables, so I wanted to use the tablename from a combobox selection rather than writing code for each table

Comment: `Paradox` perhaps you should start over and explain what it is your're trying to do based on table names from a combobox from there I think that other may be able to chime in with ideas on handle dynamic DataBinding based on a particular table

Comment: IQueryable<T> really doesn't have Local property, so can you explain where from you are getting it. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb351562(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yes, I came to know that IQueryable<T> doesn't have Local property, that's why it is giving the error. I wanted to know how do I use local with reflection.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done much with `entity-framework` but the obvious issue looks like you're attempting to cast to the wrong object here:

```
var truncatedData = ((IQueryable<object>)rawData).Local.ToBindingList();
```

I believe `rawData` is a [`DbSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) which does not implement the `IQueryable<T>` interface. Note that it does implement `IQueryable` but that isn't the generic version, nor would you be able to get the `Local` property from `DbSet` from it anyway. Changing the above line to the following may help:

```
var truncatedData = ((DbSet)rawData).Local.ToBindingList();
```

Comment: this gives error: 'System.Collections.IList' does not contain a definition for 'ToBindingList' and no extension method 'ToBindingList' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.IList' could be found